# Carbon create date not later than this month

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Does [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) come with any function which allows us to publish the current month in case the user inputs a year and month later than the current month

```
\Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate($f, $g)->endOfMonth()
```

or do we have to perform manual validation?

Comment: @caejayoz, sorry. is echo the date string and query the database

Comment: Why would Carbon have a built-in function that queries a database? You're going to have to code this in yourself. A simple `<=` comparison against `Carbon\Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()` should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not, but you can check to see if the date is in the future and handle appropriately.

```
$dt = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate($f, $g);

// Is this in the future?
if($dt->isFuture()){
     // Replace $dt with current date
     $dt = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
}
```